# What is the difference between zero dimensional tensor and item?

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

This piece of code takes lot of memory:

```
int len = Input.size(0);
at::Tensor outputs = torch::zeros({ len });
for (int SliceStart = 0; SliceStart < len; SliceStart += SliceSize)
{
  std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> InputVec;
  InputVec.push_back(Input.slice(0, SliceStart, SliceEnd));
  output = module.forward(InputVec).toTensor();
  for (int i = SliceStart; i < SliceEnd; ++i)
    outputs[i] = output[i - SliceStart];
}
```

This doesn't (note `item()` in the last assignment)

```
int len = Input.size(0);
at::Tensor outputs = torch::zeros({ len });
for (int SliceStart = 0; SliceStart < len; SliceStart += SliceSize)
{
  std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> InputVec;
  InputVec.push_back(Input.slice(0, SliceStart, SliceEnd));
  output = module.forward(InputVec).toTensor();
  for (int i = SliceStart; i < SliceEnd; ++i)
    outputs[i] = output[i - SliceStart].item();
}
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You need to add the whole code so that one can reproduce the issue.